# Button Onclick event not fires properly MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which contains the main view and a few partial views.
In a partial view I have some buttons which should go to the controller action result. The problem is that the button `onclick` event is not fired, only sometimes. I tried to put the code in the main view in a `script` tag. I have tried to put the code for `onclick` in the partial view, but it is not working properly.

I also like to mention that this partial view is rendered in more views, so I think that the `onclick` event should be present on the partial view where are the buttons.

This is the partial view:

```
<div class="row viewEdit">
    <div class="button-bar col-md-2">
       <button type="button" id="btnDamageInvoiceShow" class="btn btn-success  btnDamageInvoiceShow">@Resources.Common.ShowInvoice</button>
   </div>
    <div class="button-bar col-md-2">    
        <button type="button" id="btnDamageInvoiceGenerate" class="btn btn-success  btnDamageInvoiceGenerate">@Resources.Common.Generate</button>           
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is the code for `onclick`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".btnDamageInvoiceGenerate").on("click", function (e) {
            var idSelector = function () { return this.id; };
            var selectedDamages = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
            console.log(selectedDamages);

            console.log("idee");

            var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GenerateInvoiceDamage", "TimberMonitor", new { Area = "" })';
            var url = baseUrl + '?' + $.param({ damageIds: selectedDamages }, true);
            location.href = url;
        });

        $("#btnDamageInvoiceShow").on("click", function (e) {
            //var btn = this;
            //e.preventDefault();

            console.log("hello");

            var idSelector = function () { return this.id; };
            var selectedDamages = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
            console.log(selectedDamages);

            var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("ShowDamageInvoice", "TimberMonitor", new { Area = "" })';
            var url = baseUrl + '?' + $.param({ damageIds: selectedDamages }, true);
            location.href = url;
        });
    });
```

And this is the ActionResult from the controller:

```
 public ActionResult GenerateInvoiceDamage(IEnumerable<string> damageIds)
 { .. .}
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Try `$("body").on("click", ".btnDamageInvoiceGenerate", function(e) {` and `$("body").on("click", "#btnDamageInvoiceShow", function (e) {`  instead

Comment: Scripts should not go in partials (only in the view of its layout). Is the partial being loaded dynamically after the page has first been rendered (in which case you need event delegation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$("body").on("click", ".btnDamageInvoiceGenerate", function(e) {`
 and `$("body").on("click", "#btnDamageInvoiceShow", function (e) {` instead  and let me know if it is working or not in comments

Comment: It seems that it is working with $("body").on("click",